# How to get actual post.id while using friendly_id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, friendly-id

I currently have my post model using friendly_id to replace `Post.id` with `Post.pid`: 
`friendly_id :pid, :use => :scoped, :scope => :id`

How can I get the actual id of a post instead of the slug so that when a reply saves it saves `Post.id` and not `Post.slug` to `Reply.post_id`.

I need to do this because replies are appearing to posts created on other boards due to `post.pid` not being unique

```
class RepliesController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @board = Board.friendly.find(params[:board_id])
    @post = Post.friendly.find(params[:post_id])
    @reply = @post.replies.create(reply_params)
    @post.touch
    redirect_to @board
  end
  private
    def reply_params
      params.require(:reply).permit(:name, :email, :subject, :comment, :reply_file)
    end
end
```

Comment: Unrelated to your question: you can add `touch: true` to your `Post.belongs_to :board` association and save a line of code in your controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try scoping your `Post.find` by the board:

`@post = @board.posts.friendly.find params[:post_id]`

Comment: I get the error undefined method `posts', but it works with @board.posts.

Comment: Yeah, I got a little carried away. Fixed.